# Dual boot alongside freedos

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

My laptop came with Freedos pre-installed. Later I had installed windows 10 on it. I then noticed that the FreeDos partition was never deleted. Yesterday, I tried to install Ubuntu, while choosing to install Ubuntu, I chose the option **Install Ubuntu alongside FreeDos**, now what has happened is that the system neither boots into Windows nor Ubuntu. I don't know what to do, please help me.

Thanks in advance.